# javascript works on all browsers except IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, sorttable.js

I have some web pages that load an external JavaScript file like this:

```
<script src="sorttable.js"></script>
```

This package comes from here: [sorttable](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable)

I reference it in an onload function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() { sorttable.innerSortFunction.apply(document.getElementById("Symbol-2"), []); }
</script>
```

This works perfectly on Firefox and Chrome, but on IE version 9.0.2 it fails with these messages:

```
HTML1113: Document mode restart from IE9 Standards to Quirks 
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by javascript:void(0) 
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'apply': object is null or undefined
```

This is an internal website, and 9.0.2 is the version my company deploys, and I cannot upgrade to a newer version.

Can I make this work on IE as well as the other browsers?

Comment: Welcome to Internet Explorer, my man.

Comment: Perhaps javascript is not enabled for your actual security level on IE.

Comment: @DadyFuji - how can I tell if it's enabled or not?

Comment: http://browsers.about.com/od/internetexplorertutorials/ss/disable-javascript-ie9.htm

Comment: Thanks. I verified that javascript is enabled.

Comment: side note: your company is using IE 9 because it has internal applications it can't or just wont upgrade that were written to IE 8 standards. Do yourself and your company a favor and push IE 11 and the use of Enterprise mode, http://www.love2dev.com/#!article/Internet-Explorer-Enterprise-Mode-Resources. If they let you use Chrome they should let you use IE 11. Those applications wont work in Chrome, but they will in IE 11, plus it can be centrally managed by the IT admins, etc.

Comment: I have no control or input on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the SortTable library is using some sort of hacky browser detection in an attempt to initialize the library at the earliest possible time:

(excerpt from library source code)

```
/* for Internet Explorer */
/*@cc_on @*/
/*@if (@_win32)
    document.write("<script id=__ie_onload defer src=javascript:void(0)><\/script>");
    var script = document.getElementById("__ie_onload");
    script.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == "complete") {
            sorttable.init(); // call the onload handler
        }
    };
/*@end @*/
```

It looks like IE is rejecting this because of the attempt to use a script with the URL `javascript:void(0)` on a page accessed over HTTPS.

The library also has a catchall to use the `onload` handler if it doesn't have a browser-specific approach for the initialization:

```
window.onload = sorttable.init;
```

but you are overwriting the `onload` handler with your own, so this never executes.

I think the simplest solution is just to modify your `onload` handler to perform the initialization:

```
window.onload = function() { 
    sorttable.init();
    sorttable.innerSortFunction.apply(document.getElementById("Symbol-2"), []); 
};
```

and you should be all set. The `init()` method has an internal check to prevent it from performing the initialization twice, so you don't need to worry about issues from calling it if it has already been called.

Comment: When I added the call to sorttable.init() it then fails with this "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'innerSortFunction': object is null or undefined" - that is because the function innerSortFunction of sorttable object will be present only if there is any table with sortable class exists and it seems that the DOM elements do not exist at the time this runs. But without the sorttable.init() they do exist (but then I get the other error)

Comment: This is probably a silly question, but did you add the call to `sorttable.init()` inside the `onload` handler, or somewhere outside of it?

Comment: Inside the onload handler, just like you showed above.

Comment: I've been doing more testing with this, and I've found that if I manually reload the page this all works. But I have a reload function: setTimeout("parent.frames['header_frame'].document.submitform.submit()", 60*1000 ); and when that refreshes the page I get the "innerSortFunction': object is null or undefined" error. Any suggestions?

Comment: So this seems like a timing issue. If I replace the onload with a timeout function that waits 1 second it works 99% of the time. I really don't want to have a set timeout, and I'd rather wait for innerSortFunction to become defined. But I can't quite work out how to code it to wait for that.

Comment: I solved it by waiting for the function to exist before calling it. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely need to set your doctype correctly. If you're using `<!DOCTYPE html>`, then try adding

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

to your `<head>`.

Also, make sure there is nothing occurring before the doctype. Including whitespace and newlines. Check the output of the html, not the source from your server-side code.

Otherwise fall back to a different doctype and re-test your other browsers.

Comment: My HTML currently starts like this:
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="body.css" />
<html>
<head> It does not have a DOCTYPE. I tried add the the DOCTYPE and meta after the head, but that said: HTML1115: X-UA-Compatible META tag ('IE=edge,chrome=1') ignored because document mode is already finalized.

Comment: Which doctype did you add, and did you confirm that it is the first byte that is sent to the browser?

Comment: You have a `<link>` tag _before_ your `<html>` tag???  The DOCTYPE should be the first thing in your HTML; it shouldn't be "after the head".

Comment: I have a sickening feeling that the page is being served through a proxy which is injecting that link tag. That would be the worst case situation, and would disallow "add the doctype" as a solution :(

Comment: @Joe Frambach: I added the HTML doctype. It was not the first thing on the page. The page is being generated by PHP code. I can change it to anything I want.  I will try it with the doctype first.

Comment: DOCTYPE should be the first thing in your markup period. If it is not then IE falls into Quirks mode. Quirks mode means the browser is running as if it is the year 2000 and does some really funky things.

Answer (score -1):

It is a security issue with IE although this might fix it:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       sorttable.innerSortFunction.apply(document.getElementById("Symbol-2"), []);
   </script>
```

scripts are already synchronous, but if that doesn't work try moving the script to after the body tag

Comment: I very much doubt that using an `onload` handler is the cause of the issue here.

Comment: Actually, I have to take that back. This _is_ the result of using an `onload` handler, but that's because of poor design on the library implementer's part.